# Saber cuándo se descargó un archivo

Tags: php

Buen día.

En este momento estoy utilizando un ciclo while para saber cuando un archivo se descarga, pero no creo que sea la mejor forma.
¿Alguien conoce un método adecuado para hacerlo?

Muchas Gracias

Comment: **Es importante leer [ask]** para seguir los consejos que te dan ahí, para que sea bien recibida por la comunidad la pregunta editalá y muestra el codigo que tienes ya.

Comment: Para que tu pregunta sea mejor aceptada tienes que agregar el código que has intentado realizar, para que las personas puedan darte una mejor respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Podrias hacer contando los bytes transmitidos por el server al cliente
a su vez tambien puedes usar o detectar con : connection_aborted()

```
if (readfile($path) !== false && !connection_aborted()) {
// descarga exitosa !!
}
```

es una forma pero en esencia podria ser una via para ello deberias poner tu codigo . suerte !!